# Real Analysis : uniform convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I was working on a real-analysis problem, but I got stuck,
so could anybody please help me with this question?

Give an example of a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on the interval $[0,1]$ such that $f_n(x)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, but the supremum of $f_n(x)$ is $1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Think of spikes (an "upside down V") of height $1$ whose bases are the intervals $[0,1/n]$.

Comment: From where did you get this question if you don't mind me asking

Answer (score 1):

Idea: $f_n$ piecewise linear, $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,1-2/n]\cup\{1\}$, $f_n(1/n)=1$.