# max {$f_n(x):x\in[a,b]$}$\to$ max{$f(x):x\in[a,b]$}

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a sequence of continuous function converging uniformly to $f$.
Show that

$(1)$

> max {$f_n(x):x\in[a,b]$}$\to$ max{$f(x):x\in[a,b]$}

$(2)$ The above result does not hold for pointwise convergence.

My attempt for($1$): As $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ so they attain their bounds on$[a,b]$,

Let max {$f_n(x):x\in[a,b]$}=$f_n(x_k)$ ,$\forall n\geq k$and

max{$f(x):x\in[a,b]$}=$f(x_0)$.

Now as $f_n\to f$ uniformly so corresponding to given $\epsilon>0$ there exist $k(\epsilon)\in\mathbb N$ such that

> $\forall x\in[a,b]$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon $, $\forall n\geq k.$
>
> In perticular$|f_n(x_k)-f(x_k)|<\epsilon$.........$(1)$ and
>
> $|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$...............................$(2).$ $\forall n\geq k.$

Now to show that ,

> $|f_n(x_k)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$,$\forall n\geq k.$
>
> Now,$|f_n(x_k)-f(x_0)|$=$|f_n(x_k)-f(x_k)+f(x_k)+f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|\leq |f_n(x_k)-f(x_k)|+|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|+|f(x_k)|+|f_n(x_0)|\leq2\epsilon+|f(x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)|\leq2\epsilon+|f(x_0)|+|f_n(x_k)|,\forall n\geq k.$

Is this approach correct? Please help. Give me a counterexample to show $(2)$ Thanks.

Comment: The counterexample: see my answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654659/real-analysis-uniform-convergence-of-sequence.

Comment: In your link it is asked $f_n\to 0$? not $max f_n (x)$?

Comment: And what about $(1)?$

Comment: $\max f_n=1\ne 0=\max f$.

Comment: okkkk. What do you think for 1.

Comment: May we need some monotone on $f_n$ like Dini's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Your (1) is too complicated and the required conclusion does no follow. There is no need of the $x_k$. Try this:

Let be $x_0$ like you; by the uniform convergence,
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$
for $n\ge k(\epsilon)$. Said inequality is equivalent to
$$f(x)-\epsilon < f_n(x) < f(x)+\epsilon.$$
As $x_0=\max f$,
$$f(x)-\epsilon < f_n(x) < f(x_0)+\epsilon.$$
By definition of max,
$$f(x)-\epsilon < f_n(x)\le\max f_n \le f(x_0)+\epsilon.$$
Particularly,
$$f(x_0)-\epsilon \le\max f_n \le f(x_0)+\epsilon.$$
That is equivalent to
$$|\max f_n-f(x_0)|\le\epsilon.$$

Comment: How max $f_n\leq f(x_0)$?

Comment: $f_n(x)<f(x_0)+\epsilon$ for **all** $x$.