# Let $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a sequence of continuous function converging uniformly to $f$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $\,f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a sequence of continuous function converging uniformly to $f$.
Show that

$$
\max \{\,f_n(x):x\in[a,b]\}\longrightarrow \max\{\,f(x):x\in[a,b]\},
$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Wasn't this asked a few hours earlier?

Comment: yes, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655842/max-f-nxx-ina-b-to-maxfxx-ina-b).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $x_n\in [a,b]$, such that $f_n(x_n)=\max_{x\in [a,b]} f_n(x)$, while
$f(x_*)=\max_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)$.

Since $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then there is an $n_0$, such that $n\ge n_0$ implies that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$, for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Hence, for $n\ge n_0$, $|f_n(x_*)-f(x_*)|<\varepsilon$, and thus
$$
f(x_*)<f_n(x_*)+\varepsilon\le f_n(x_n)+\varepsilon, \tag{1}
$$
and $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|<\varepsilon$, and thus
$$
f_n(x_n)<f(x_n)+\varepsilon\le f(x_*)+\varepsilon. \tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain
$$
f(x_*)-\varepsilon<f_n(x_n)<f(x_*)+\varepsilon,
$$
or equivalently, for every $n\ge n_0$:
$$
|f_n(x_n)-f(x_*)|<\varepsilon.
$$
This is the same as saying: For every $n\ge n_0$
$$
\left|\max_{x\in[a,b]}f_n(x)-\max_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)\right|<\varepsilon.
$$
Ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι.